# How to call webservice method from my UI class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website + webservice in the same project. I would like to call a webservice method from my partial class which extends System.Web.UI.Page. This method is actually inside webservice and inside a class.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. What method is inside the webservice and in the class??. If you have the web service in the same web site why don't you extract that method in a helper class and call this helper class from your Page class?

Comment: I don't know, probably because I'm ASP noob. But you gave me the idea :D

Comment: ok Now I know :), if you have any question only ask

Comment: Thank you for help. Appriciate this. :)